# Need help understanding OpenCL reductions

Tags: opencl

I have been reading the following note:
http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/

The following kernel should reduce a chunk of data and theres one part of it i simply dont understand.

```
while (global_index < length) ....  global_index += get_global_size(0)
```

I belived that it was smarter to read data from global storage that was sequential layed out. Meaning reading data at k, k+1, k+2 is faster then reading k+1000, k+2000, k+3000. Is this not what they are doing when saying global_index += get_global_size(0) ?

```
__kernel
void reduce(__global float* buffer,
            __local float* scratch,
            __const int length,
            __global float* result) {

  int global_index = get_global_id(0);
  float accumulator = INFINITY;
  // Loop sequentially over chunks of input vector
  while (global_index < length) {
    float element = buffer[global_index];
    accumulator = (accumulator < element) ? accumulator : element;
    global_index += get_global_size(0);
  }

  // Perform parallel reduction
  int local_index = get_local_id(0);
  scratch[local_index] = accumulator;
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  for(int offset = get_local_size(0) / 2;
      offset > 0;
      offset = offset / 2) {
    if (local_index < offset) {
      float other = scratch[local_index + offset];
      float mine = scratch[local_index];
      scratch[local_index] = (mine < other) ? mine : other;
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  }
  if (local_index == 0) {
    result[get_group_id(0)] = scratch[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work items 0,1,2,3,... will first read buffer indices 0,1,2,3,... in parallel (this is generally the best case for memory access), and then 1000,1001,1002,1003,... in parallel, etc.

Remember that each instruction in the kernel code will be executed "in parallel" by all work-items.

Comment: AHh, that is correct. I was thinking that one kernel at a time reading. Back to the drawing board redesigning kernels :)

Comment: Dont that mean that get_global_size should be equal to the number of work items being spawned at the same time?

Comment: Yes, global size *is* the number of work-items scheduled for execution "at the same time". The input buffer may be much larger than that, and it's the purpose of the while loop: cover the entire buffer in chunks of "get_global_size(0)" elements. At the end of the while, each work-item has the min value of "his" slice of the data.

Comment: ... then the second part of the kernel does a reduction within the work-group, using shared memory to communicate values inside the work-group. At the end of kernel execution, each work-group will have produced one single min value.  A second pass will be needed to reduce  the data further to one single element.

Comment: I should then find out how many simultaneous work items my gpu board support and set that as global size and set the length equal to the number of elements in the buffer.? Any easy way to calculate how many items a device can spawn?

Comment: You usually want more work-items than what can physically run simultaneously. The only reliable way to figure out is benchmarking.

Comment: Is it not just something like compute units times times workitems pr CU ? But guess i dont really know how many work items pr CU i have. One last question if you dont mind. The trivial vector add kernels that is normally presented when learning opencl. Is it not stupid to do out[global_id] = in_a[global_id] + in_b[global_id]. Should one not use the same princip of having work items that run together use the memory that are close together? Or is that what really happens, and the case above is different because the while loop comes to play?

Comment: Yes, the vector add kernel you describe has the same good access pattern.